# If you type website.com/test, does Github Pages redirect you to website.com/test.html or website.com/test/index.html?

Tags: redirect

I made the experiment for all of you, in case you wondered, and the result is...

Answer (score 0):

It redirects you to website.com/test.html

Only if said page is deleted, it redirects you to website.com/test/index.html
I don't the rules behind it though.

If this experiment gets negative voting because it is obsolete, I will delete it.